# Make a value within a countifs function return a 0 for a "yes" and make no change if "no"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Table]

I need to exclude the 5th column(I) if M8 says Yes, but I always get a error. If it says No, there shouldn't be a change in the number.

The current code is `=COUNTIFS(Dat!12:12,E$4,Dat!4:4,$N$6,Dat!4:4,$N$7)`

I've tried `=COUNTIFS(Dat!12:12,I$4,Dat!4:4,$N$6,Dat!4:4,$N$7,IFS(M8="Yes",0),0)`, and `=COUNTIFS(Dat!12:12,I$4,Dat!4:4,$N$6,Dat!4:4,$N$7,IM8="Yes",0)`

Preferably I would like it to be able to drag throughout the entire table, but if it's only possible to make it work for just the 5th column, that would work fine.

[image]

This would be the desired outcome, everything in column 5 set to 0 if M8=Yes.

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to do? Post few sample data then desired output. I assume, you have to use two `COUNTIFS()` or some other formula like `FILTER()` then count.

Comment: `=if($m$8="Yes",0,countifs(.....))` should do the trick, or to go further `=if(and($m$8="Yes",column()=5),0,countifs(.....))`.  Let us know how you get on with it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @InjuredCoding for your help.

[image: Yes]

[image: No]

The final code is `=IF(AND($M$8="Yes",COLUMN()=9),0,COUNTIFS(Dat!12:12,E$4,Dat!4:4,$N$6,Dat!4:4,$N$7))`

The only change I made from @InjuredCoding suggestion is the column, excel registers column 5 as E, so I switched the column to 9.